# How do pilots and flight attendants themselves refer to flight attendants casually?

Tags: terminology, flight-attendant

If, say, a pilot is referring casually to a flight attendant friend (e.g. in an epithetical description), do they use "flight attendant"? It seems a bit of a mouthful.

For example:
A pilot is chatting to someone and they say something like "I have a flight attendant friend."

Would they simply use the complete phrase "flight attendant," or are there any other ways they might do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Typically, "flight attendant." It isn't generally shortened, the way that "first officer" can be shortened to "FO" (pronounced as two letters, not "foe") or simply to "pilot". In writing, the Flight Attendant position is often abbreviated to "FA", but it's rare to hear it spoken as those two letters.

The old single-word term "stewardess" hasn't been used in decades, and the shortened slang form of that, "stew," is heard pretty rarely; almost always it's simply "flight attendant."

Comment: At least in my experience, I hear "cabin crew" used frequently, as well.